# Library not Loading/Image not Found - Swift 4.0

Tags: swift4, ios-frameworks, xcode9.3

So I am very new to Swift and XCode. I am trying to use an external library called `JJFloatingActionButton` the projects build fine but when I try run it on an emulator I get:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/JJFloatingActionButton.framework/JJFloatingActionButton
  Referenced from: /Users/mkangwa/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/
3E58C8A1-3F02-4CA0-8EF3-A79311A202A2/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/D8BBF9A8-5BC7-4619-
B08C-2E6F7C6BCB85/DriversHub-iOS.app/DriversHub-iOS
  Reason: image not found
```

Now of course I know you can't come ask a question like this on StackOverflow without researching and trying to find a solution yourself, so thats what I've been doing for the past few hours I have been looking at what was causing this, I started thinking that maybe it was the library it's self so this one is the third or fourth I've tried till I came across a few posts on SO that were about this issue.

Most people fixed this by just putting the Framework into the `Embedded Binaries` in the targets General Settings. And I tried this but I now receive a log:

[image: No such file or directory]

I also get a **Dependancy Analysis Warning:**

[image: Dependancy Analysis Warning]

**I don't know much about these types or warning and errors** but it's saying that it can't find the file which is pretty self explanatory but when I am adding the file to `Embedded Binaries` it shows the framework file there

Comment: What do you use to integrate the framework? Cocoapods?
Or better: How do you build the library?

Comment: I am using Cocoapods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it took a day and a half to work this out but I have finally got it and I can carry on with my project.

**Problem:**

The problem in my particular case (because other methods seemed to have worked for people trying to achieve the same thing) that the reason my project wouldn't build and was throwing Build Time errors was because after adding the Framework to `Embedded Binaries` it was also adding it to `Embed Frameworks` in my targets Build Phases. This then, I believe, caused the compiler to try and build it twice hence the `Multiple Build Commands` error

**Solution:**

So the errors I kept getting where saying `No such file or directory` above it was saying `Multiple build commands for output file` and what I did to fix this I went to **Build Phases** in my target settings and deleted the framework from **Embedded Frameworks** but made sure it was still under `[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks`.

Answer (score 1):

What I often do when I have problems with cocoapods is remove cocoapods from the project and reinstall it.

You could use `pod deintegrate` (https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoapods-deintegrate) to remove it and then a `pod install` to reinstall.

Comment: Thanks for this but I ended up finding a solution

Answer (score 0):

in my case I was have to make framework "embed & sign" in stead of "don't embed"

[image]